# How to add different yup validation when field is dependent on other field values. if else-if else validation

Tags: javascript, validation, yup

I want something like this but multiple is-then conditions not working in yup.

```
foo: Yup.string().when(['bar'], {
    is: (e) => e===0,
    then: Yup.string()
      .required('foo-1 is required'),
    is: (e) => e===1,
    then: Yup.string()
      .required('foo-2 is required'),
    otherwise: Yup.string()
      .optional()
  })
```

Please provide a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

We can provide a function that returns a schema (called with the value of the key and the current schema)

```
foo: Yup.string().when('bar', (e, schema) => {
    if (e === 0) {
      return schema.string().required('foo-1 is required');
    } else if (e === 1) {
      return schema.string().required('foo-2 is required');
    } else return schema.string().optional();
  })
```